# NetworkOnMainThreadException with retrofit-beta2 and rxjava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I recently upgraded from retroft-beta1 and this was working. I have the following interface for the API:

```
public interface Service {
    @POST("path")
    Observable<Object> service();
}
```

And the following call:

```
service.service()
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe();
```

And it throws a NetworkOnMainThreadException. But this was working in retrofit-beta1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From retrofit-beta2, calls to Observable methods [now behave synchronously](https://github.com/square/retrofit/releases/tag/parent-2.0.0-beta2). So `subscribeOn` must be used:

```
service.service()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe();
```