# NetworkOnMainThreadException when Observable subscrible rxjava

Tags: java, android, rx-java, observable, rx-java2

I'm working with Rxjava2,

I'm using `flatmap` in RxJava with below structure:

`Observable1.flatmap()` and return to Observable 2.

as below codes :

```
getApi().createUser(os, deviceToken)
            .compose(view.regisObserver())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(result -> {
                String user_token = result.data.user_token;
                getPreferenceStore().setAuthToken(user_token);

                setReadPolicy();

                Observable<ObjectDto<UserProfile>> obs = getApi().updateProfile(null, null, null);
                        obs.compose(view.regisObserver());

                return obs;
            })
            .subscribe(result-> {
                getPreferenceStore().setUserId(result.data.user_id);

            //                    view.onUpdateProfile();
            }, Throwable::printStackTrace);

@Override
public <T> ObservableTransformer<T, T> regisObserver() {
    return observable -> observable.compose(prepare())
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> showProgressDialog())
            .doOnComplete(this::closeProgressDialog)
            .doOnError(throwable -> {
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }
                showProgressDialog();
                closeProgressDialog();
            });

}
```

The code compiles without error. It got error in run-time `NetworkErrorOnMainThread`. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You should not run any network calls on MainThread, Use a separate thread.

Comment: Cmon, it has been answered so many times... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349334/rxjava-and-retrofit2-networkonmainthreadexception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687907/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-using-rxjava-on-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390532/networkonmainthreadexception-with-retrofit-beta2-and-rxjava http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447077/android-rxjava-non-blocking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify that you want to subscribe on non-UI thread...for example

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

Actually, looks like you are doing that for `updateProfile`....just need to also do it for `createUser`

Comment: It's helpful, but not solve yet.

Comment: You're still getting `NetworkErrorOnMainThread` after adding that?  Can you add full error you're getting + your updated code.